# Optimizing long running WebAPI method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a WebAPI function which performs a loop calculation to find a single numerical value.

From my client side javascript, I make around 20 simultaneous requests to this function for a single page load. I have confirmed through Chrome's network performance tool that all the requests are made at the same time but the requests receive responses sequentially (the initial ones take .2 seconds, with the later ones taking up to 8s) so the server appears to be the bottleneck.

I have tried optimizing my code by making it async, though I'm not sure I did it correctly or that it improved the performance at all.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<double> CalcResult(double First, double Second)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(()=>LoopCalculationFunction(First,Second));
    return result * 100;
}
```

Is this done properly and is there any way I can further optimize this function?

Comment: So, after `async-await` implementation do you see any performance boost at client? The further optimization, if required, I guess should be to fix complexity in `LoopCalculationFunction`?

Comment: You may be hitting Chrome's connection limit: http://superuser.com/questions/499114/how-to-increase-chromes-connections-per-server

Comment: Also, this is an improper usage of `Task.Run`. It achieves nothing and, in fact, is harmful. See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your client-side javascript to batch calls up, ideally into a single request. Pass an array of `first` and `second` values and get an array back.

1) Each round-trip is slow, you can make it faster with a single round-trip.

2) You will hit browser per-server (or per-profile) limits for simultaneous connections.

3) This isn't an appropriate use of `Task.Run`, see http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

4) If your total connection time is too large you should move to a polling API: post the calculation request and then poll for progress and the eventual result.

Comment: These are great suggestions. I suppose restructuring my client side code to bundle the requests is doable. Once I do this, I can use linq parallels to run the function, eliminating all the unnecessary http requests. Something I did not think of.